# When does ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup actually guarantee cleanup?

Tags: .net, reliability

I have been reading about [Reliability Features in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163716.aspx) and have written the following class to explore [`ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.executecodewithguaranteedcleanup.aspx)

```
class Failing
{
    public void Fail()
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(Code, Cleanup, "fail");
        }
    }

    private void Code(object message)
    {
        // Some code in here that will cause an exception...
    }

    private void Cleanup(object message, bool something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have experimented with a variety of code bodies for the `Code` method. These, and their runtime results are listed below

Causing an `OutOfMemoryException` - `Cleanup` **does not** get called

```
List<string> ss = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
    string s = new string('x', 1000000);

    ss.Add(s);
}
```

Causing a `StackOverflowException` - `Cleanup` **does not** get called

```
Code(message); // recursive call
```

Causing a `ExecutionEngineException` - `Cleanup` **does not** get called

```
Environment.FailFast(message.ToString());
```

Causing a `ThreadAbortException` - `Cleanup` **does** get called (however a regular `try...finally` can also catch this exception)

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
```

So the questions are

- Am I using `ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` correctly?
- When is `ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` actually useful?

Comment: Run this code on a CLR host that implements ICLRPolicyManager.  SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some exceptions are fatal to the process and execution of user-supplied code just does not continue. The purpose of `ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` method is to so you can put your data structures back in a consistent state. If the process is going to die anyways with no way to stop it, this has no purpose. The OS (assuming it is working properly) will clean up any kernel objects automatically for you when a process ends, regardless of the reason the process ends.

As Hans hints, the `ICLRPolicyManager` of the host comes into play to determine which exceptions are fatal in this way when code is run in a particular host (especially SQL Server). See the nice grid at the bottom of this documentation page: [ICLRPolicyManager::SetActionOnFailure Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164395.aspx)

Comment: Old answer, so documentation and behavior may have changed, I'm not sure, but [MSDN currently says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.probeforsufficientstack?view=netframework-4.8) _"If you are calling a recursive method or plan to use a lot of stack space, you must use the RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup method."_. This suggests at least that a `StackOverflowException` can be prevented with that method.